# Can JUnit assertions be called from a method not annotated with @Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

If I have the following class:

```
public class MyTest
{
   @Test
   public void testSomething()
   {
     Something myData = new Something();
     testAccordingToData(myData);
   }


   @Test
   public void testSomethingElse()
   {
     Something myOtherData = new Something("something else");
     testAccordingToData(myOtherData);
   }

   private void testAccordingToData(Something someData)
   {
     assertTrue(somedata.someField);
     assertEquals(someData.someField, someData.someOtherField);
     //and various other assertions based on someData
   }
}
```

Would the assertions in `testAccordingToData()` work as normal, or can assertions only be called from the method which is annotated with `@Test`?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: You would be smarter if you could work out really simple questions for yourself.  This way you can weight up many considerations at once in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree, but it wasn't a really simple question though. May be for someone experienced with JUnit, yes, but not for someone new to it.

Comment: You can't possibly learn every library and what it does but if you can read its code you can always work it out quickly enough.

Comment: You already wrote the methods when you asked the question.  It would have taken you 10 seconds to add a "main" method to `MyTest` and run it.  Certainly less time than it took you to ask the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace No, I wrote some psuedo code to get the point across.

Comment: Looks like valid Java to me.  And you could have used an existing class instead of inventing `Something`.  Really, Stack Overflow has de-generated lately.  It has become the "Why should I make any effort to find out the answer for myself, when there's sure to be someone in the world who's bored enough to find it out for me" site.   I'm strongly with Peter Lawrey on this one.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't have a `Something` class. In actual code, I've had to write 3 different maps and 2 lists in order to generate the data to test this. I wasn't interested in writing that before knowing if it would actually work or not. I don't know about you, but I would rather ask for directions than drive for 2 hours to see if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Are you saying it would have taken you hours to write one class, containing `public static void main(String[] args){assertTrue(false);}` ?  I now understand your earlier remark about being a productive programmer.

Comment: @DavidWallace That alone wouldn't have answered my question. My question was about what happens when a method with `@Test` annotation calls another method without `@Test`, and the 2nd method does the asserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

junit "assertions" are just simple method calls.  they can be called from anywhere.

Comment: I see. But, if I have 5 assertions, and if assertions 1-2 pass but assertion 3 fails, then the assertions 4 and 5 seem to not be called at all. If How does that happen if they're simple method calls?

Comment: @ClickUpvote - a failing assertion throws an exception.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I was finding it mysterious how it worked.

Comment: @ClickUpvote The Assert class is one of the simplest classes to understand from reading.  In many cases it's methods are just one to three lines with a dozen lines of documentation.

Comment: @jtahlborn A failing assertion does NOT throw an `Exception`; it throws an `Error`.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @DavidWallace - no, they aren't the same class.  yes, they have the same effect.  so, what's your point?

Comment: My point, @jtahlborn, is that we, the Stack Overflow community, every last one of us ... are creating a resource that will live forever, and be available to millions, maybe billions of programmers over the course of time.  Wouldn't you rather have information in it that is CORRECT, rather than information that is "the same effect" as correct information?

Comment: @DavidWallace -  at this point in time, probably 90% of the questions answered on SO are re-hashes of already answered problems.  not sure that this answer will have quite the impact on history that you envision.  that said, my comment was "exception", not "Exception", so i didn't even specifically name a class.  if you wanted to point out the specific class thrown, maybe you could do that without quite the drama and feigned outrage in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most complicated chain in Assert.  You can see it has nothing to do with annotations and it throws an AssertionError which is not surprising given this is what it does when an assertion fails.

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
                                Object actual) {
    if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
        return;
    } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else {
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}
```

checks with

```
private static boolean equalsRegardingNull(Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null) {
        return actual == null;
    }

    return isEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

calls on failure

```
static private void failNotEquals(String message, Object expected,
                                  Object actual) {
    fail(format(message, expected, actual));
}
```

which calls

```
static public void fail(String message) {
    if (message == null) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    throw new AssertionError(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's uncommon, but often wise, to create a custom assertion method.  One usually names the method something like `assertFoo`.

These days, one can create a custom Hamcrest matcher.

Finally, you commented above about wanting to see the results of all the failing assertions.  In that case, JUnit 4.8 and higher have a solution for you. Look at the [ErrorCollector](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) `@Rule`.